# Rails bug in Active Record Model

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I was practicing my Code and soon I found that '.order' method works in reverse. My rails version is '5.0.0.1'

I used it like:

(i) User.order(salary: :desc).first(3)

(ii) User.order(salary: :desc).first(3)

I got reverse results. I am using mysql database. Can anybody tell me whether its mine mistake or really it's rails problem.

Comment: can you post some output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get ascending order result, you should be doing Ascending instead of Descending. The following code will sort the `salary` in ascending order and get the first 3.

`User.order(salary: :asc).first(3)`

The code that you provided below will sort the salary in descending order, and then select the first 3.

`User.order(salary: :desc).first(3)`

Example: given an array with unsorted value [3, 2, 4, 5, 1]. After the following code is executed, you will have the results as below

 `User.order(salary: :desc)` >>> `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`
`User.order(salary: :desc).first(3)` >>> `[5, 4, 3]`

 `User.order(salary: :asc)` >>> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
`User.order(salary: :desc).first(3)` >>> `[1, 2, 3]`